# Получить ссылку на страницу сообщения на форуме

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, алгоритм

На форуме сообщения хранятся в таблице с автоинкрементом "id"...

На каждой странице выводится условно по 10 сообщений. Сообщения могут удаляться модераторами, из-за чего сообщения на страницах смещаются.

Как получать ссылку на сообщение по его id, с совершенно другой страницы, например для ассоциаций как здесь. Ведь можем в поле для ассоциаций хранить только id - потому что номер страницы может меняться.    (Ссылки имеют вид URL/.../[номер страницы]).

Например можно по id получить номер страницы вот так:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM имя_таблицы WHERE id < "id для которого ищем ссылку"
```

Затем делим на число сообщений на странице, и узнаем на какой странице будет сообщение с нашим id.

Может математики подскажут как сделать что-то наподобие индикатора плотности:

```
  Ident1 = f1(Ident, idDel);  numId=f2(Ident, id);
```

Где f1() - функция вызываемая при удалении сообщений, Ident текущий индикатор плотности, Ident1 - обновленный индикатор плотности.

f2() - функция вызываемая при поиске номера(numId) сообщения, а соответственно и его страницы, по id сообщения для которого ищем страницу.

Естественно эта система должна быть быстрее чем COUNT(*).
Такое вообще возможно?

Еще можно сделать страницу редиректа, которая принимает номер сообщения и редиректит пользователя на искомую страницу, так можно избавиться от поиска ссылки для каждой выводимой ассоциации, а искать только для той по которой пользователь кликнет.

Какой способ получения страницы сообщения оптимальный?

Comment: Вы уж определитесь. Либо Вы хотите ссылаться на сообщение, либо на страницу, на которой это сообщение находится. Но не одновременно. Как по мне - первое и правильнее, и проще. А вот если юзер отправится по ссылке - сервер сам посчитает номер страницы, и выдаст именно ту, на которой находится целевое сообщение.

Comment: @Akina Лучше на страницу сообщения и промотать до самого сообщения. Но вторая часть легко делается с помощь атрибута "name".   Но если искать страницу сообщения каждый раз долго, то придется на сообщение ссылку делать.   Понятно первое проще, а почему оно правильнее? Ведь пользователь не может продолжить читать дальше(если там одно сообщение), если сообщение и последующие, то  нужно приделывать пагинацию чтобы без повторов сообщений была. Опять же возможно поисковики найдут эти вторые варианты страниц и за дубли накажут и т.д.

Comment: Тогда я согласен с @S.H. - наплюйте на начальное деление на страницы ядовитой слюной, и просто выводите сообщение по ссылке - либо самым первым на странице, либо средним, либо ещё как. Подумаешь, границы при начальной пагинации и при этой не совпали - так они по-любому поплывут, если кто-то что-то сделает (скажем, удалит промежуточное сообщение)... а главное - ну на что они влияют-то? кто на них смотреть будет?

Answer (score 2):

По моему, Вы сами ответили на Ваш вопрос:

так как на id сообщения нельзя опираться для получения id страницы (так как некоторые из сообщений могут быть удалены), то можно получать id страницы, исходя из кол-ва сообщений с id, меньшим данного.

Этот способ - неплохой, но у него есть пара недостатков: 1) "вы не можете выдать страницу, не используя весь массив предшествующих данных" - то есть, не посчитав кол-во сообщений 2) в зависимости от того, сколько сообщений удалено - номер страницы, на котором лежит конкретное сообщение, может меняться. То есть, ссылка с номером страницы ("заходя на страницу M я хотел увидеть сообщение N"), которая была актуальна вчера, может быть неактуальна сегодня. Удалили какие то собщения "за прошлое время" - номер страницы поменялся.

*Я не знаю оптимального способа*, но мне приходит в голову способ "отвязаться от номера страницы, оперировать только id сообщения".

Пускать по каждому id сообщения мы показываем страницу, где **это конкретное** сообщение на самом верху страницы, а под ним - еще 9 других ("не удаленных") сообщений.

Если же id соответсвует удаленному сообщению - то можно этот факт отобразить однйо строкой, а под ним показать уже 10 нормальных, не удаленных сообщений.

При этом способе у сайта будет больше "страниц", но так как все страницы - виртуальные, это может не играть никакой роли.

Comment: Видел такой способ, сделаю его если искать порядковый номер сообщения(как я описал) окажется медленно и  не придумаю(не подскажут) способ лучше.  Но хотелось бы чтобы все же можно было перейти по ссылке и сразу читать продолжение форумного общения.

Comment: @Hertz *хотелось бы чтобы все же можно было перейти по ссылке и сразу читать продолжение форумного общения.* То есть перейти таки к сообщению... а тогда не пофиг, на какой оно странице?

Comment: @Akina Если пользователь хочет прочитать больше страницы продолжения, тогда как быть? Выводить новые при прокручивании, еще, как выше писал- дубли страниц это плохо с точки зрения СЕО- придется закрывать от поисковиков...

Comment: @Hertz Ну если Вы всё же хотите жёсткую привязку к страницам, то либо процедура определения номера страницы по номеру сообщения, либо предрасчётная обновляемая отдельная таблица такого соответствия. И тут всё пляшет от того, какие действия выполняются над сообщениями, предусмотрена ли процедура удаления сообщения, и что при этом происходит с пагинацией (пересчёт, или оставляется неполная страница). *придется закрывать от поисковиков* А поисковикам - версию "для печати" в зубы, и пусть радуются.

Comment: @Akina Благодарю. За одно может подскажете как наименее затратно искать страницу? Через  COUNT(*) как я в вопросе описал, или может есть более быстрые варианты? Пагинация смещается- иначе, скажем наспамил злодей, а после удаления пустые страницы будут.  Вы говорите таблицу под цели храниения держать, а завернуть в число как я в вопросе писал точно не выйдет(я сам сильно сомневаюсь если что)?

Comment: @Hertz Ну мимо COUNT() тут как бы не пройти. Другое дело что даже на индексированном списке `SELECT COUNT WHERE id < @id` может оказаться не самым производительным запросом. Вот тут как раз и может помочь предрасчётная таблица. Например, она может держать количество записей в каждой тысяче id-ов - тогда расчёт номера текущей записи во всём списке будет выполняться более сложным запросом, но намного быстрее, ведь надо будет посчитать только количество записей в текущей тысяче и сумму в предыдущих. Впрочем, лично мне этот подход не нравится...